# How to Fancy-Index Into a PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: python, indexing, pyspark, databricks

I have a PySpark DataFrame like:

```
|id1 | id2 |
------------
|100 |abcd |
|201 |efgh |
|112 |ijkl |
|133 |mnop |
```

And a python list of `id2`s like:

```
mylist = ['abcd', 'ijkl', 'efgh', 'efgh', 'abcd', 'ijkl', 'ijkl']
```

I'd like to use the pyspark dataframe to map the values in my list into the corresponding `id1` values, so:

```
desired_result = [100, 112, 201, 201, 100, 112, 112]
```

I'm doing it now with Pandas but it takes a really long time this way, since the lookup table has millions of rows. How can I do this in PySpark?

Comment: Why dont you create a dataframe from your list and join it with the lookup dataframe?

Comment: `df.join(spark.createDataFrame([(x,) for x in mylist], ["id2"]), on="id2").select("id1").show()`. You can `collect` the result if you want it in a `list` and you can also `broadcast` the second DataFrame since it's small. (Caveat: be careful not to rely on the order of the elements in the list.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create a DataFrame from your list, `df2` below:

```
a = [(100, 'abcd'),(201, 'efgh'),(112, 'ijkl'),(133, 'mnop'), (245, 'qrt')]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(a, ['id1', 'id2'])
mylist = ['abcd', 'ijkl', 'efgh', 'efgh', 'abcd', 'ijkl', 'ijkl']
ml = [(idx, k) for idx, k in enumerate(mylist)]
print(ml)
df1.show()
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(ml, ['id', 'name'])
df2.show()
```

They are shown below:

```
[(0, 'abcd'), (1, 'ijkl'), (2, 'efgh'), (3, 'efgh'), (4, 'abcd'), (5, 'ijkl'), (6, 'ijkl')]
+---+----+
|id1| id2|
+---+----+
|100|abcd|
|201|efgh|
|112|ijkl|
|133|mnop|
|245| qrt|
+---+----+

+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  0|abcd|
|  1|ijkl|
|  2|efgh|
|  3|efgh|
|  4|abcd|
|  5|ijkl|
|  6|ijkl|
```

2. Join the DataFrames and use the `id` column to keep the original order

```
df = df2.join(df1, df1.id2==df2.name).orderBy('id')
df.show()
[r.id1 for r in df.select('id1').collect()]
```

Final output:

```
+---+----+---+----+
| id|name|id1| id2|
+---+----+---+----+
|  0|abcd|100|abcd|
|  1|ijkl|112|ijkl|
|  2|efgh|201|efgh|
|  3|efgh|201|efgh|
|  4|abcd|100|abcd|
|  5|ijkl|112|ijkl|
|  6|ijkl|112|ijkl|
+---+----+---+----+

[100, 112, 201, 201, 100, 112, 112]
```

Comment: This works for my use case! Thanks a bunch :)  I guess there's no fancy indexing.